# SAS color series separately in SGPLOT

Tags: sas

#### Let's say I have four X-Y plots that I want to plot on the same figure. How can I color each line plot separately?

I've tried the below code:

```
proc sgplot data = band;
*styleattrs datacolors=(lightblue red green blue black purple brown yellow);
series x = X  y = a /markerattrs=(color=green);
series x = X  y = b /markerattrs=(color=blue);
series x = X y =c /markerattrs=(color=lightblue);
series x = X y =d /markerattrs=(color=red);
run;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost did it

```
proc sgplot data = band;
series x = X  y = a /lineattrs=(color=green);
series x = X  y = b /lineattrs=(color=blue);
series x = X y =c /lineattrs=(color=lightblue);
series x = X y =d /lineattrs=(color=red);
run;
```

By the way, `datacolors=` only take effect on different group, not different plot.